# Get record based on combination of values of a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables : option_combination & option_combination_mapping

**option_combination**

- option_combination_id
- product id
- quantity
- price

[image]

**option_combination_mapping**

- id
- option_combination_id
- option_id
- option_value_id

[image]

I have an array of option_value_id and product_id, I want the record where the product_id and all the option_value_id of my array are mapped.
If say my array is (11,7,9), there are mappings for same product for say (11, 7, 10)
Using this query i get the mapping for (11,7,9) but I also get the mappings for 11,7 of (11,7,10)

> SELECT * FROM `oc_option_combination_mapping` ocm LEFT JOIN
>   `oc_option_combination` oc ON (ocm.`option_combination_id` =
>   oc.`option_combination_id`) where oc.product_id = 4 AND
>   ocm.`option_value_id` IN (11,7,9)

[image]
I tried this query which is giving be desired result but for only one combination

> SELECT * FROM `oc_option_combination` oc LEFT JOIN
>   `oc_option_combination_mapping` ocm ON (oc.`option_combination_id` =
>   ocm.`option_combination_id`) where oc.product_id = 4 AND
>   ocm.`option_value_id` IN (11,7,9) HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT
>   ocm.`option_value_id` = 3)

[image]
when I try for another combination 11,7, 10 :

> SELECT * FROM `oc_option_combination` oc LEFT JOIN
>   `oc_option_combination_mapping` ocm ON (oc.`option_combination_id` =
>   ocm.`option_combination_id`) where oc.product_id = 4 AND
>   ocm.`option_value_id` IN (11,7,10) HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT
>   ocm.`option_value_id` = 3)

[image]
I get the same result again whereas it should fetch the record with option_combination_id 2 and not with option_combination_id 1

I need help to fetch price and quantity for various different unique combinations of option_value_id of a product with the query.

For example the result of query should be the record with option_combination_id 1 (price 10) for option_value_id (11,7,9) and product_id 4 and the result of query should be the record with option_combination_id 2 (price 20) for option_Value_id (11,7,10) and product_id 4

Comment: Is there a question buried in there?

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes i need to fetch the quantity and price for combinations of option_value_id for a product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last one is almost correct, just you moved the `=3` into the `count()`, but it should be outside of it. Also, you missed the group by clause:

```
SELECT oc.option_combination_id
FROM `option_combination` oc
INNER JOIN `option_combination_mapping` ocm ON (oc.`option_combination_id` = ocm.`option_combination_id`)
where oc.product_id = 4 AND ocm.`option_value_id` IN (11,7,10)
Group by oc.option_combination_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ocm.`option_value_id`)=3
```

I also changed changed the left join into an inner one since you filter on the right hand siďe table anyway.

Comment: 'Group by oc.option_combination_id' did the magic :) thanks a lot for your help